# character reading in C

Tags: c, character

I am struggling to know the difference between these functions. Which one of them can be used if i want to read one character at a time.

```
fread()

read()

getc()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by "one character at a time".

If you want to ensure that only one character is consumed from the underlying file descriptor (which may refer to a non-seekable object like a pipe, socket, or terminal device) then the only solution is to use `read` with a length of 1. If you use `strace` (or similar) to monitor a shell script using the shell command `read`, you'll see that it repeatedly calls `read` with a length of 1. Otherwise it would risk reading too many bytes (past the newline it's looking for) and having subsequent processes fail to see the data on the "next line".

On the other hand, if the only program that should be performing further reads is your program itself, `fread` or `getc` will work just fine. Note that `getc` should be **a lot** faster than `fread` if you're just reading a single byte.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you want to do it you can use any of those functions.

The easier to use would probably be `fgetc()`.

`fread()` : read a block of data from a *stream* ([documentation](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/))

`read()` : posix implementation of `fread()` ([documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read))

`getc()` : get a character from a *stream* ([documentation](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getc/)). Please consider using `fgetc()` ([doc](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/))instead since it's kind of saffer.

Answer (score 1):

`fread()` is a standard C function for reading blocks of binary data from a file.

`read()` is a POSIX function for doing the same.

`getc()` is a standard C function (a macro, actually) for reading a single character from a file - i.e., it's what you are looking for.

Comment: No.  The answer is `fgetc()`.  Well OK, it doesn't matter but I think it's better to use the function than the macro version.

Comment: @JeremyP: That seriously depends on what you're doing. As long as one is aware that `getc()` is allowed to evaluate its parameters more than once, there is nothing wrong with using the macro - *especially* in tight loops where you don't want to pay the function call penalty on each iteration. (And you usually *do* read single characters in tight loops...)

Comment: And boy, do I hate these drive-by downvotes. In what way is my answer "not useful"?

Comment: @DevSolar: the down vote wasn't me.  However, I don't think your argument about the tight loop really holds much water.  The first character you get will cause I/O to be performed which will take a orders of magnitude longer than a the difference between getc and fgetc.

Comment: Depending on what kind of I/O device you're addressing - SSD devices aren't *that* expensive anymore, for example - 8192 function calls (`BUFSIZ` on your average Linux) can very well amount to a significant amount of clock cycles. But that's neither here nor there - the question wasn't about `getc()` vs. `fgetc()`, but about the three functions mentioned above. Ah well...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, also note that `read` is unbuffered method to read from a file. `fread` provides an internal buffer and reading is buffered. The buffer size is determined by you. Also each time you call `read` a system call occurs which reads the amount of bytes you told it to. Where as with `fread` it will read a chunk in the internal buffer and return you only the bytes you need. For each call on `fread` it will first check if it can provide you with more data from the buffer, if not it makes a system call (`read`) and gets a chunk more data and returns you only the portion you wanted. 
 Also `read` directly handles the file descriptor number, where `fread` needs the file to be opened as a `FILE` pointer.

Comment: Are you sure that it says in the specification of `read()` that it is unbuffered? I don't think so. Actually the manpage of `read()` explicitly states that NFS file systems *do* cache (and thus don't update time stamps as expected), so I assume whether `read()` is buffered or not is up to the file system.

Comment: the POSIX read manual does not tell anything the NFS access. The Linux read manual does say it, although it also says "Unix semantics can be obtained by disabling client side attribute caching, but in most situations this will substantially increase server load and decrease performance." I think i a closer look is needed in the case of NFS, and what the standard.